# lsblk incorrect readonly

Tags: lsblk

Hi I'm trying to detect ro filesystem mainly for root partition
This is portable system using usb as OS disk
The state is readonly, I cannot write anything

```bash
touch /tmp
touch: setting times of '/tmp': Read-only file system
```

lsblk output

```bash
lsblk /dev/sdb

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1 28.7G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1  512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   1 15.5G  0 part /
```

This is the json output

```json
{
  "blockdevices": [
    {
      "name": "sdb",
      "kname": "sdb",
      "path": "/dev/sdb",
      "maj:min": "8:16",
      "fsavail": null,
      "fssize": null,
      "fstype": null,
      "fsused": null,
      "fsuse%": null,
      "fsver": null,
      "mountpoint": null,
      "label": null,
      "uuid": null,
      "ptuuid": "cc59543f-1263-436b-b654-441947b5d432",
      "pttype": "gpt",
      "parttype": null,
      "parttypename": null,
      "partlabel": null,
      "partuuid": null,
      "partflags": null,
      "ra": 128,
      "ro": false,
      "rm": true,
      "hotplug": true,
      "model": "SanDisk_3.2Gen1",
      "serial": "0401915ccab85f2287ceb131fd353892d7ae4b148e3eff697bb2af15fdab6e26684500000000000000000000899c7a1b00827b18915581076eab2054",
      "size": "28.7G",
      "state": "running",
      "owner": "root",
      "group": "disk",
      "mode": "brw-rw----",
      "alignment": 0,
      "min-io": 512,
      "opt-io": 0,
      "phy-sec": 512,
      "log-sec": 512,
      "rota": true,
      "sched": "mq-deadline",
      "rq-size": 2,
      "type": "disk",
      "disc-aln": 0,
      "disc-gran": "0B",
      "disc-max": "0B",
      "disc-zero": false,
      "wsame": "0B",
      "wwn": null,
      "rand": true,
      "pkname": null,
      "hctl": "52:0:0:0",
      "tran": "usb",
      "subsystems": "block:scsi:usb:pci",
      "rev": "1.00",
      "vendor": " USB    ",
      "zoned": "none",
      "dax": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "sdb1",
          "kname": "sdb1",
          "path": "/dev/sdb1",
          "maj:min": "8:17",
          "fsavail": "506M",
          "fssize": "511M",
          "fstype": "vfat",
          "fsused": "5M",
          "fsuse%": "1%",
          "fsver": "FAT32",
          "mountpoint": "/boot/efi",
          "label": null,
          "uuid": "6729-75FE",
          "ptuuid": "cc59543f-1263-436b-b654-441947b5d432",
          "pttype": "gpt",
          "parttype": "c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b",
          "parttypename": "EFI System",
          "partlabel": null,
          "partuuid": "54ce8d01-e9bc-434b-9971-5d31ded28098",
          "partflags": null,
          "ra": 128,
          "ro": false,
          "rm": true,
          "hotplug": true,
          "model": null,
          "serial": null,
          "size": "512M",
          "state": null,
          "owner": "root",
          "group": "disk",
          "mode": "brw-rw----",
          "alignment": 0,
          "min-io": 512,
          "opt-io": 0,
          "phy-sec": 512,
          "log-sec": 512,
          "rota": true,
          "sched": "mq-deadline",
          "rq-size": 2,
          "type": "part",
          "disc-aln": 0,
          "disc-gran": "0B",
          "disc-max": "0B",
          "disc-zero": false,
          "wsame": "0B",
          "wwn": null,
          "rand": true,
          "pkname": "sdb",
          "hctl": null,
          "tran": null,
          "subsystems": "block:scsi:usb:pci",
          "rev": null,
          "vendor": null,
          "zoned": "none",
          "dax": false
        },
        {
          "name": "sdb2",
          "kname": "sdb2",
          "path": "/dev/sdb2",
          "maj:min": "8:18",
          "fsavail": "8.1G",
          "fssize": "15.2G",
          "fstype": "ext4",
          "fsused": "6.2G",
          "fsuse%": "41%",
          "fsver": "1.0",
          "mountpoint": "/",
          "label": null,
          "uuid": "f769a7b6-9d09-4bc7-9249-85f50d4a1c2e",
          "ptuuid": "cc59543f-1263-436b-b654-441947b5d432",
          "pttype": "gpt",
          "parttype": "0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4",
          "parttypename": "Linux filesystem",
          "partlabel": null,
          "partuuid": "0cf31261-d5f9-4182-894c-283bd8fb62ad",
          "partflags": null,
          "ra": 128,
          "ro": false,
          "rm": true,
          "hotplug": true,
          "model": null,
          "serial": null,
          "size": "15.5G",
          "state": null,
          "owner": "root",
          "group": "disk",
          "mode": "brw-rw----",
          "alignment": 0,
          "min-io": 512,
          "opt-io": 0,
          "phy-sec": 512,
          "log-sec": 512,
          "rota": true,
          "sched": "mq-deadline",
          "rq-size": 2,
          "type": "part",
          "disc-aln": 0,
          "disc-gran": "0B",
          "disc-max": "0B",
          "disc-zero": false,
          "wsame": "0B",
          "wwn": null,
          "rand": true,
          "pkname": "sdb",
          "hctl": null,
          "tran": null,
          "subsystems": "block:scsi:usb:pci",
          "rev": null,
          "vendor": null,
          "zoned": "none",
          "dax": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

in lsblk RO column it shown as 0
in the json format readonly also mark as false

But when check in /proc/mounts it shown as ro ( /dev/sdb2 )

```bash
cat /proc/mounts

/dev/sdb2 / ext4 ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

So lsblk cannot read the correct state ?

Running from debian 11
lsblk from util-linux 2.36.1

I need the output for notification, preferably using lsblk since it has json format.

I also found that /proc/mounts sometime have strange record for non root

```bash
# correct fstab but here different disk in same mount 
# 2 of them ro , 1 of them rw
/dev/sdk1 /mnt/disk-***0G ext4 ro,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdo1 /mnt/disk-***0G ext4 ro,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdq1 /mnt/disk-***0G ext4 rw,noatime 0 0
```

Test on findmnt

```bash
├─/mnt/disk-***0G          /dev/sdk1  ext4          ro,noatime
│ └─/mnt/disk-***0G        /dev/sdo1  ext4          ro,noatime
│   └─/mnt/disk-***0G      /dev/sdq1  ext4          rw,noatime
│     └─/mnt/disk-***0G    /dev/sdl1  ext4          rw,noatime
```

Non root disk mount with UUID with this options
It's not that important to stale the OS if it is error, but need to know if it is error.

```
defaults,nofail,noatime,x-systemd.device-timeout=10s,errors=continue 0 0
```

Comment: `lsblk` only displays whether the device itself is read-only. As `cat /proc/mounts` is showing that it is read-only, it has been mounted as such via `/etc/fstab`, the `mount` command, or some other method.

Comment: I just found out /proc/mounts sometime has multiple same entry. So not quite easy to find out which one is correct

Comment: They are both correct. `lsblk` shows the device as being not read-only because it isn't whereas `cat /proc/mounts` shows the filesystem as being read-only because it is. You said yourself in a reply to the answer below that the `/etc/fstab` has the option `errors=remount-ro`.

Comment: For root partition it only show as one, this one I can find a way to catch it.
But for normal partition ( using findmnt and mount same mount target appear multiple time for different disk ). Problem with x-systemd perhaps ....

Answer (score 2):

As Nasir said in the comments, the `RO` column in the `lsblk` output is about the device being read-only, not the filesystem. So if it's read only because the filesystem is mounted with the `ro` option `lsblk` won't show it, because the device itself is still read-write. `lsblk` can show you only the device "state":

```
$ lsblk -o+RO /dev/sde3
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS RO
sde3   8:67   0  10M  0 part              0

$ sudo blockdev --setro /dev/sde3

$ lsblk /dev/sde3
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sde3   8:67   0  10M  1 part
```

If you want to check whether the filesystem is mounted as readonly you need to check for the `ro` or `rw` mount option (conveniently `mount` will mount read-only devices with the `ro` option by default so you don't need to check both the device and filesystem). You can use `findmnt` to do that so for example something like

```
$ findmnt -n -o options /dev/sde3
ro,relatime,seclabel


$ findmnt -n -o options /dev/sde3 | grep -q ^ro && echo "read only"
read only
```

Comment: hmm, I set the options in fstab to errors=remount-ro, since it is a flash disk sometime it get mounted to ro maybe due to some corrupt fs. 

sometime the ssh key exchange will be error under this circumstances. so I know it was flash disk problem. But sometime it's not , currently I use touch to detect it.